# I'm creating docx file in c# using Docx library. when i click create button its not overwrite the document. it repeated display. how i can do that

Tags: c#, ms-word, docx

[image: enter image description]

DocX document = DocX.Load(@"F:\BIIT\Project\LetterTemplate\sample.docx");

```
            //Insert a Text into the document. 

            Paragraph p3 = document.InsertParagraph();
            p3.Append("to introduce  ").Italic().Font(new FontFamily("Times New Roman"));
            p3.Append(txtname.Text);
            p3.Append(" S/o ").Italic();
            p3.Append(txtfathername.Text);
            p3.Append("of our institute was enrolled in");
            p3.Append(txtprog.Text);
            p3.Append("program under University registration No. ");
            p3.Append(txtaridNo.Text);
            p3.Append("during academics session ");
            p3.Append(txtsession.Text);
            p3.AppendLine();
            p3.AppendLine();
            p3.AppendLine("In this connection I would request you to provide him the opportunity to acquire practical knowledge and would appreciate your willingness to accept him as");
            p3.Append("internee").Bold();
            p3.AppendLine("in your esteemed organization");

            p3.AppendLine();

            document.Save();
```

OUTPUT

to introduce - our institute was enrolled in(BSCS)program under University registration academics session 2013-2017

In this connection I would request you to provide him the opportunity to acquire practical knowledge and would appreciate your willingness to accept him asinternee
in your esteemed organization

to introduce  S/o our institute was enrolled in(BSCS)program under University registration No. academics session

In this connection I would request you to provide him the opportunity to acquire practical knowledge and would appreciate your willingness to accept him asinternee
in your esteemed organization

Comment: If I get your question right, you're asking why repeatedly executing this code adds more and more to the same document? The reason is that you load the document, add stuff to it, then save it using the same filename. See if you can save it as a new file instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I looked in the code, you can't make that if you use Load and Save, because you are opening the document and append text.

So you have the option to create a new document, and append the text, or also you can use SaveAs as saving method, and make a differente filename for each document you create.

Comment: I hope that is enough for you.